# phpstorm snap missing desktop

Tags: 16.04, snap, xdg, azure

Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel: 4.13.0-1012-azure)
Snap 2.32.3.2
Snapd 2.32.3.2

I tried installing phpstorm via `sudo snap install phpstorm --classic`.

I can see that phpstorm is installed and can be run from the command line, however the desktop launcher is missing. I can see the .desktop file in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/phpstorm_phpstorm.desktop`. The odd thing is I have installed phpstorm via snap on another VM using the ubuntu 16.04 iso. Is there another configuration I'm missing? I'm using xrdp to remote into this machine and can see that my `XDG_DATA_DIRS` is missing which included the snapd path on the VM that worked. Also if I SSH into this Azure VM I can see the `XDG_DATA_DIRS` in my env dump. So perhaps this isn't a snap issue but two different ubuntu images with how environment variables are set up in the profile on login.